# Python 2.7 - Define Basic Operators for Specific Classes

Tags: python, operators

I'm creating a module in Python to store and manipulate data as Quaternions (composed of a real element **w** and a vector element **v = xi + yj + zk**. Creating the quaternion class for storing the data is simple:

```
class quaternion_c:

   def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
      self.w = w
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.z = z

   ...
```

What I want to do is, in tandem with using custom methods for performing arithmetic on `quaternion_c`, I want to be able to use basic operators on the instances themselves in much the same way NumPy Arrays use them. In short, given two example `quaternion_c` objects:

```
qtn0 = quaternion_c(0, 1, 2, 3)
qtn1 = quaternion_c(100, 99, 98, 97)
```

I want `qtn0 + qtn1` to produce the same results as:

```
def add(qtn0, qtn1):
   w_01 = qtn0.w + qtn1.w
   x_01 = qtn0.x + qtn1.x
   y_01 = qtn0.y + qtn1.y
   z_01 = qtn0.z + qtn1.z

   return quaternion_c(w_01, x_01, y_01, z_01)

add(qtn0, qtn1)
```

I would also like to specify similar changes to other operators, like `*` for `mult()` and `**` for `exponent()`. Is this doable? Is it possible to change how basic operators handle specific classes?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: @Ryan: I was still searching for the duplicate, you beat me to it :)